# How to debug GWT Projects in JDB?

Tags: debugging, gwt, jdb

I m having a GWT Eclipse Project , i m using Eclipse to debug the Project. The GWT Project is dependent on other projects too. Its really easy using Eclipse debugger, but consumes more memory. The Java Process consumes 500MB and eclipse around 500 MB, so does firefox(GWT Plugin) . So i would like to use JDB for debugging my GWT Project.

How can i do that and how to attach Tomcat server to jdb ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT has actually nothing special regarding debugging: just launch the DevMode with the appropriate JVM argument (something along the line of `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n` for a Sun/Oracle VM) and then attach to it with JDB to debug both the client-side code and the server-side code running within the embedded Jetty.

As for Tomcat, adding `jpda` to the command line (`catalina jpda start` instead of `catalina start`) should be enough: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing (note: the `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp` is the old-style way, before Java 5 shipped with *agents* and the `-agentlib` switch; `-agentlib` is preferred: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation )

Comment: Thanks ,i'll try this, i have another doubt too. Since its ui projcet, i don't have main function in my java program. So JDB obviously gives me errors.  Can i debug servlets and UI projects in jdb ..?

Comment: A Java program must have a main class with a `main` method. In this case, they are GWT's `DevMode` and Tomcat's `Bootstrap`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to debug Servlets in JDB ..? How can i debug GWT's Dev Mode or even Tomcat's Bootstrap from JDB ..?